# Unable to drop a column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported a Excel sheet into pandas. It has 7 columns which are numeric and 1 column which is a string (a flag).

After converting the flag to a categorical variable, I am trying to drop the string column from the Pandas dataframe. However, I am not able to do it.

Here's the code:

```
[In] parts_median_temp.columns

[Out] Index([u'PART_NBR', u'PRT_QTY', u'PRT_DOL', u'BTS_QTY', u'BTS_DOL', u'Median', u'Upper_Limit', u'Flag_median'], dtype='object')
```

The column I'm trying to drop is 'Flag_median'.

```
[In] parts_median_temp.drop('Flag_median') 

[Out] ...ValueError: labels ['Flag_median'] not contained in axis
```

Help me drop the `Flag_median` column from the Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 63):

You have to use the ***inplace*** and ***axis*** parameter:

```
parts_median_temp.drop('Flag_median', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The default value of 'inplace' is **False**, and axis' default is **0**. axis=0 means dropping by index, whereas axis=1 will drop by column.

Comment: I wonder why this is not the correct answer. Because I tried [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), but this is the one that worked for me.

Comment: Or parts_median_temp.drop(columns='Flag_median', inplace=True)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
parts_median_temp = parts_median_temp.drop('Flag_median', axis=1)
```

Comment: This hadnt worked. Had to include inplace=True to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @Learnerbeaver It works, you just have to change the dataframe so you put  `parts_median_temp =` in front of the drop function. So, I edited my answer. I thought that was obvious.